# Setting the initial value of a UILABEL

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to create a simple Quiz app (I'm a beginner), when I launch the app I want a UILabel to show the first question (of an array of questions). I'm having some trouble with setting the initial value.

I've done a couple of attempts, whiteout success. I my QuizAppDelegate.h file I declare my UILabel like this:

```
 IBOutlet UILabel * questionField;
```

In my main .m file I have tried the following:

```
- (id)init {

    [super init];

    questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Not working
    questionField = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [questionField setText:@"Hello"];

    // Working
    NSLog(@"Hello");

    [self defaultQuestions];
    // [self showQuestion];

    return self;
}
```

Another thing I have tried is the following in QuizAppDelegate:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *questionField;

- (void)changeTitle:(NSString *)toName;
```

And in the .m file:

```
@synthesize questionField;

- (id)init {

    [super init];

    questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Not working
    [self changeTitle:@"Hello"];

    // Working
    NSLog(@"Hello");

    [self defaultQuestions];
    // [self showQuestion];

    return self;
}

-(void)changeTitle:(NSString *)toName {
    [questionField setText:toName];
}
```

Any tips on how to solve this would be great!

// Anders

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully you're not actually putting code into `main.m`. On iOS, you rarely modify that file.

Since you're doing everything in the AppDelegate, let's keep it there (as opposed to creating a new `UIViewController`). Let's start with the basics.

**Adding the Label as an instance variable**

You're doing this correctly—inside the curly braces of the `.h` file, put the line

```
IBOutlet UILabel * questionField;
```

Then, declare the corresponding property, and make sure to synthesize it in the `.m` file.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *questionField;
@synthesize questionField    // in the .m file
```

---

**Adding the UILabel in Interface Builder**

Open up `MainWindow.xib`. Drag a UILabel from the Library to the Window that represents your app's window. Then Control-Drag from the AppDelegate object (the third icon on the left in Xcode 4; it'll be labelled in the Document window in IB 3). You'll see a little black window come up—select the option called `questionField` to make the connection.

See [this link](http://www.idev101.com/learn/interface_builder_connections.html) for screenshots and how to make connections in IB. The same applies in Xcode 4.

---

**Changing the text**

You don't need a separate method to change the text—just modify the label's `text` property.

Pick a method that'll be called when the app launches (`applicationDidFinishLaunching:WithOptions:` is a good place to do it in), and put the following code:

```
questionField.text = @"Hello";
```

And that's it!

---

**Code**

*QuizAppDelegate.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface QuizAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UILabel *questionField;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *questionField;

@end
```

*QuizAppDelegate.m*

```
#import "QuizAppDelegate.h"

@implementation QuizAppDelegate

@synthesize window=_window;
@synthesize questionField;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    [self.window addSubview:self.questionField];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.questionField.text = @"Hello";
    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [questionField release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: If you were to create a new `UIViewController` subclass, go for the View-Based Application template. Then declare the ivar and property in the `.h` and put `self.questionField.text = @"hello";` in the `viewDidLoad` method. Make sure to release the label in `dealloc` if you're `retain`ing it—which you should.

Comment: I think didFinishLaunchingWithOptions was the secret sauce. Would have taken a long time to figure that out. So thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating the label programmatically, then you have to add the label to the view:

```
[self.view addSubview:questionField];
```

This assumes that you have a `ViewController`. If not, and you're doing this directly in the `AppDelegate` (a very bad idea, by the way), then do

```
[self.window addSubview:questionField];
```

If you're creating it in the IB, make sure you set up the connections.

You should **not** both add the UILabel in the IB and instantiate it programmatically. Only call `alloc` if you are creating it programmatically. Otherwise, if using the IB, skip that part. You created it already with the xib.

Comment: ...but this: IBOutlet UILabel * questionField; implies the view is built using IB.

Comment: Implies, perhaps, but only if the programmer really means that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the following error by putting this in my .m file: QuizAppDelegate.m: error: Semantic Issue: Property 'view' not found on object of type 'QuizAppDelegate *'. Yes, I have used interface builder.

Comment: Set up a ViewController or else add the view to the window.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have either not created your Interface Builder layout properly - either you have missed the control out all together or more likely you have not connected that control to the `questionField` outlet in yout header file.

You need to drag a UILabel view into the main view and then connect it to the correct line in your header file.

Comment: Hi, I have (cntrl) dragged from the UILabel to IBOutlet UILabel * questionField; And I have imported <UIKit/UIKit.h> in my header file. I have a coupe of other classes, do I need <UIKit/UIKit.h> there as well?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using your `main.m` like that at all.  In fact, you should almost certainly never do anything with it.  Try creating a `UIViewController` subclass and practicing your quiz with that. (Add the UILabel to the IB file and then connect the outlet.)  Perhaps use the View-Based Application template while you are practicing.

Comment: `UIViewController` is a good option, but for beginners working with just a Window-Based Application is also a good option.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good answer:
"You're doing this correctly—inside the curly braces of the .h file, put the line

IBOutlet UILabel * questionField;"
 I was trying to change the value of mylabel.text and the screen didn't update the label with this.value. I included the {IBOutlet UILabel * mylabel} and it works like a charm!
So this answer is valid to change the text of a label programmatically!
Thanks